# Importing signatures into Petition?

Tags: civicampaign

I am bringing old data into CiviCRM and we have a number of old petitions in a variety of formats (paper, YAWPP) and I didn't see a way to import the old names & emails into a petition. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

So I figured out how to do this, for the future.

You need to import an Activity for each contact. Match as per any other import

Key import details:

- source_record_id = petition id (you may have to look into the db to find this)
- activity type = 32 (or the activity type id listed for Petition Signature in Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Activity Types)
- subject = by default, this is the title of petition
- data = date signed

Comment: @Corery during import with which option did you associate the source_record_ID?

Comment: Afaict, the source_record_id is the numeric value of the survey/petition id in the appropriate database table (I run it on Wordpress, so the table is called civicrm_survey)

Comment: I know, but during a petition impot with which option/label do you associate the source_record_ID? If we associate it with "activity ID" it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Sorry, yes. Activity ID I think is the campaign id, but I wasn't using it for this upload